# printing common characters in three strings

Tags: c

Q)  Write a c program that takes as input three strings, each of maximum 30 characters, and
prints common characters present in all three strings. Each string can have different number of
characters.

The code i have written is:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c1=0 , c2=0, c3=0 ,i,x;  
    int count1[26]={0} , count2[26]={0} , count3[26]={0};  
    char st1[30],st2[30],st3[30];  
    printf("enter string1: ");  
    gets(st1);  
    printf("\n enter string2: ");  
    gets(st2);  
    printf("\n enter string3: ");
    gets(st3); 

    while(st1[c1]!='\0')  
    {
        count1[st1[c1]-'a']++;  
        c1++;
    } 

    while(st2[c2]!='\0')    
    {
        count2[st2[c2]-'a']++;   
        c2++;
    }

    while(st3[c3]!='\0')
    {
        count3[st3[c3]-'a']++;
        c3++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(count1[i]!=0 && count2[i]!=0 && count3[i]!=0)
        {
            if (count1[i]<count2[i] && count1[i]<count3[i])
            {
                for(x=0;x<count1;x++)
                {
                    printf("\n %c ",x+'a');
                }
            }
            else if(count2[i]< count1[i] && count2[i]< count3[i])
            {
                for(x=0;x<count2;x++)
                {
                    printf("%c",x+'a');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(x=0;x<count3;x++)
                {
                    printf("%c",x+'a');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i run the code in codeblocks,continuous randomcharacters are occuring with continous beep beep sound till i shut down the system. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The beep sounds are nagging alerts to prompt you to indent your code properly. :-)

Comment: @MOehm The poster seems to be a new user who may not understand your intended meaning (think non-native English speakers). I'm not trying to be a buzzkill - but maybe you could clarify that it is sarcasm?

Comment: Also, if you turn on yur compiler warnings, you'll be told that comparisons such as `x < count1` compare integers with pointers; you'll want `x < count1[i]` here.

Comment: Do you expect the input to contain only lowercase letters? No uppercase letters, no numbers, no other non-whitespace characters?

Comment: @metacubed: Point taken. It wasn't meant to be bitter sarcasm, though, just a funny remark I couldn't resist posting. If you don't mind, I'll leave the comment. I've seen worse on SO and the code layout really is horrible. For example, the real error is buried in the unspaced batch `{for(x=0;x<count1;x++)`. (I have to admit that some of my early "works" look similar, however.)

Comment: @MOehm Oh I don't mind the sarcasm :) I hate seeing badly formatted code too. Just felt that I was honor-bound to post my reply :P

Comment: You can do this in O(m+n+k) time using a lookup table (which you at least appear to be trying to do). But you're assuming all chars are strictly lower case, in the a-z english alphabet, and a-z are contiguous (which they are *not* on several platforms). I see nothing to indicate you can make *any* of those assumptions in the posted instructions of the assignment. And `gets()` is so evil it has been *removed* from the language standard library. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: You may find [this interesting](http://ideone.com/HvHfLK). Best of luck.

Comment: @user3628999: Did you find the solution and did any of the posts help? If so, please don't forget to upvote and/or mark one as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues that contribute to the problem. 
Here they are in the order I solved them:
(Compile-time)

1. As M Oehm mentioned in the comments, `x < count1` is invalid as you are trying to compare an integer with a pointer. This should instead be `x < count1[i]` and so on for the other blocks where there is a similar comparison.
2. `gets()` is unsafe and it's recommended to use `gets_s()` or `fgets()`instead. [Here's](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) why.

(Logical)

1. `printf("%c",x+'a');` should instead be `printf("%c", i +'a');` i.e. you should take the character value of `i` (not x) before adding `a` to it as `i` is the variable keeping track of which alphabet you are looking at in that loop.
2. If you only want to print out the alphabets that are repeated (e.g. *abc*), not the sequence of characters (*aabbccc*), the `if`, `else if`, `else` and `for` sections within your final `for(i=0;i<26;i++)` loop are unnecessary. All these can be removed safely and the final section of your code could be replaced with the following:

(please take note of the indentation and improve it throughout your program)

```
for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
{
    if(count1[i]!=0 && count2[i]!=0 && count3[i]!=0)
    {
        printf("%c", i+'a');
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that the three input strings are all "aaabbc", your loop would print "abc", whereas it seems that the OP intends to print "aaabbc"

Comment: Good answer. There is a point in the many nested `if`s and loops when printing: If the three strings share thee o's, this should print "ooo". The way it is done with three independent loops is awkward, though. And `char(i)` is C++ rather than C; there's no need to cast because in C, `'a'` is an integer, not a char and `%c` expects an integer.

Comment: @user3386109: Agreed, I interpreted the question as wanting to only print the common characters singly.

Comment: @MOehm: Ah, it makes sense now. Re: `char(i)` noted and edited, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: thanks a lot. i am new to coding and dont know many things. Sorry that my coding is bad at which i am trying to improve on.

Answer (score 1):

There are various errors in your code.

- When you print the common characters, your loop is:

  ```
  for (x = 0; x < count1; x++) ...
  ```

  but `count1` is the address of your array, which is usually a huge number. Your loop runs longer than you expect; it accesses memory locations beyond `count[25]` that contain random data (at least none your algorithm can make sense of) and prints it. (The beep sound comes from printing the character with ASCII code 7, the alert or bell code `'\a'`. If you were on MS-DOS, you'd see some happy black and white faces too.)

  The correct loop runs to the number of letters stored in `count1` for letter `i`.

  ```
  for (x = 0; x < count1[i]; x++) ...
  ```
- When you count letters, you increase

  ```
  count1[st1[c1] - 'a']++;
  ```

  This will evoke the dreaded *undefined behaviour* when `st1[c1] - 'a'` is not in the range from 0 to 25. That can easily happen, e.g. if your string is `"New York"`. You either need to check that the character lies in the correct range or you need to extend your solution to the full range of characters. (Note that the assignment talks about characters, not letters.)
- When you print the common characters, you don't print them correctly:

  ```
  printf("%c", x + 'a');
  ```

  Here, `x` is running from 0 to the number of occurrences of the letter `i`. If your common characters are thee o's, this will print "abc". You should print `i + 'a'`. (This is just a logic error, not something that can crash your program.)